# SSRS - How to hide a row with a 0 value when sorting on a column

Tags: sorting, reporting-services

I have a report that identifies all the 'Risky' types of transactions performed by a Cashier. Each 'Risk' is a column in the report. I have enabled sorting on each column. However, the user wishes to eliminate results with a 0 value on a column they select to to sort on. For example, see below:

[image: Report snippet]

So if the user chooses to sort on 'No Sale Risk', all the rows that have a 0 No Sale Risk will be hidden. If the user then selects to sort on Transaction Void Count, then all the records with a 0 Trans Void Count would be hidden. If the user sorts on CashierNo, then no rows would be hidden, etc.

I assume this would be an expression in the 'Sort by' option on Interactive Sorting:

[image]

But I have no idea how to implement this - can anyone help me with the expression?

Comment: You are describing a filtering capability which SSRS doesn't support. The visibility is all calculated once when you run the report. The closest you could get to this would be to have the user select a parameter for what they want to view/hide/sort etc. than click "View Report" again.

Comment: Thanks Steve - I will try that approach instead (using a parameter to specify the 'Sort' column and use this in the query to eliminate the 0's for that column).

Comment: What you need to achieve this without parameters, is to find a way to know which column is being sorted and using that value with an =IIF() function to make the row visisble or not based on the sort option chosen and the value of the element being greater than zero. This would be easy peasy if it were a gridview using codebehind